# How to apply `git diff` patch without Git installed?

Tags: git, diff, patch

How can my client apply patch created by `git diff` without git installed?
I have tried to use `patch` command but it always asks file name to patch.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this if the patch includes renames? Does patch support that natively now?

Comment: The question should really be: *is there a way* to apply a git diff without git installed?  [As noted below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17958129/519015), `patch` doesn't fully support this format.

Answer (score 457, accepted):

```
git diff > patchfile
```

and

```
patch -p1 < patchfile
```

work but as many people noticed in comments and other answers patch does not understand adds, deletes and renames. There is no option but `git apply patchfile` if you need handle file adds, deletes and renames.

---

**EDIT** December 2015

Latest versions of `patch` command (2.7, released in September 2012) *support most features of the "diff --git" format, including renames and copies, permission changes, and symlink diffs* (but not yet binary diffs) ([release announcement](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7361)).

So provided one uses current/latest version of `patch` there is no need to use `git` to be able to apply its diff as a patch.

Comment: Or use `git diff > patchfile`, but `patch -p1 < patchfile`

Comment: If you want to create a patchfile of a subpath of the repository you can use the `relative` option like: `git diff --no-prefix --relative=my/relative/path > patchfile`

Comment: Doesn't this require git to be installed? The question is how to do it without git right?

Comment: `patch -p1 < patchfile` does not require git installed. The first command demonstrates command for generating diff, not applying it.

Comment: The patch generated is for the changes **from** the branch/refspec indicated in the command **to** the current or active branch. In other words, you want `git diff from_branch > patchfile; git checkout from_branch; git patch -p1 < patchfile` or `git diff from_branch to_branch > patchfile; ...`

Comment: @AndreyKouznetsov That works! Could you explain what does `-p1` mean?

Comment: @PaulChechetin As egor83 said in suppie's answer it strips slash in the beginning.

Comment: As noted in [Sola Yang's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17958129/519015), `patch` does not fully understand the git diff format, so this is unfortunately not a complete solution.  It might work most of the time, but eventually a case will arise in which it doesn't work.  You should either get the diff in a fully supported format or use git to apply the diff.

Comment: Even with the -p1, my patch utility on Solaris asks for a file to patch. There are no renames or anything, this is just a simple patch file. This solution does NOT work for me.

Comment: I guess things have changed (for better): the proposed solution works for me, even if creating, renaming and deleting files. (I'm using `git version 1.8.3.2` from package `dev-vcs/git` and `patch 2.6.1` from package `sys-devel/patch` in Gentoo.)

Comment: not even git understand its own diff format. try `git diff 123..123 | git apply` use proper commit ids. it will complain about everything. even blank line at EOF.

Comment: Question was "How to apply `git diff` patch _without_ Git installed?" and answer is "git" seriously??

Answer (score 79):

try this:

```
patch -p1 < patchfile
```

Comment: What does the -p1 argument do?

Comment: Strips slash in the beginning. See [man patch](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?patch+1)

Comment: @chrisjlee `git diff` will put `a/` and `b/` prefixes in the output, so `patch -p1` neglects those to apply the patch file.

Answer (score 51):

Use

```
git apply patchfile
```

if possible.

```
patch -p1 < patchfile
```

has potential side-effect.

`git apply` also handles file adds, deletes, and renames if they're described in the `git diff` format, which `patch` won't do. Finally, `git apply` is an "apply all or abort all" model where either everything is applied or nothing is, whereas patch can partially apply patch files, leaving your working directory in a weird state.

Comment: +1, The only sane answer. Moreover, diff/patch won't handle symlinks, which is a problem if (for example) you are reverting the 3.10 Linux kernel patch.

Comment: Yes, `git apply` is the best way to do it, but this question specifically asks how to apply the patch *without Git installed*.

Comment: Options `--dry-run --verbose` are useful to determine what the side effects will be, if any. (using patch v2.5.8)

Comment: @ignis - *"`git apply patchfile -` ... the only sane answer..."* - that's almost laughable. Every time the OpenSSL devs send me a patch to test, Git fails to apply it. That's ***every*** time. I've yet to see that stupid tool apply a patch.

Answer (score 9):

I use

```
patch -p1 --merge < patchfile
```

This way, conflicts may be resolved as usual.

Answer (score -25):

Try this:

```
$ git apply file.diff
```

Comment: See question: "without git installed"