# Getting script error in YouTube Python download script

Tags: python, download, youtube

When I try to download the playlist with the [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/documentation.html) Python script I get this error.

> no fmt_url_map or conn information found in video info

[Error no fmt_url_map or conn information found in video info with specific video](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/108) explains the problem and solution, but I don't know how can I apply the solution.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly fine with videos:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl.git
$ ./youtube-dl  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHkPiU9YAQk
```

Then you can play the video "VHkPiU9YAQk.mp4"

Also with playlists:

```
$ ./youtube-dl --playlist-start=1 --playlist-end=1 http://www.youtube.com/my_playlists?p=AA0F3A8E116E1219
```

Check the parameters you are using.

Comment: No no , i am not saying its not working always but with some playlists it gives error like mentioned in the link provided. In the link he is telling to apply the pach using diff and i don't know how to do that

Comment: I couldn't find where he says there is a patch... in any case follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418277/how-to-apply-git-diff-patch

Comment: i am sorry , i think i gave the wrong link this link here https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/108