# Working with web designer in Spring MVC project using Git

Tags: spring, git, spring-mvc

I am working with a web designer that is making the JSP pages (really HTML pages) for my Spring MVC project.  We have the designer make the HTML pages and them I take them and add the Springs tags to them.  I have my project in git and the design has been emailing me the pages.

But I am looking for a better work flow.  If the designer gives me the pages in html and then I add the all the Spring tags and the user wants a change the designer is sending me html again and I have to redo all my springs tags.  Does anyone know of a better way to do this flow.  also I dont want the design to have access to my full project in git if I give them git access.. can we somehow only give them access to one folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of options:

1. Email the designer the JSP pages with the tags embedded, and ask him or her to apply changes to that page.
2. Use a branch in git for accepting the designer's HTML submissions.  Merging this branch into a trunk can replay the steps of replacing tokens, as long as the incremental changes are small (the entire DOM isn't rewritten with every submission)
3. Let him or her clone your git repository.  Not sure why you're afraid to do this, but there are such things as NDAs to protect yourself legally.  If I were he or she, I'd be bringing this up in every single meeting with you.

Comment: Ultimately that's up to you.  But remember that you both have a common goal: to make a great website.  Your web designer likely wants your project to be a success, as something to point to in a portfolio.  He/she is less likely to want to have a reputation for screwing clients.

Answer (score 0):

Try maintaining patches instead. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418277/how-to-apply-git-diff-patch-without-git-installed) and [here](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git)