# Is there an equivalent svn command for `git add --patch`?

Tags: git, svn

Looking for an equivalent svn command to the selective adding and committing in git:

`git add --patch`

Comment: Subversion doesn't have an equivalent to Git's index, and as far as I know completely lacks the concept of a partial commit. Aside from manually moving some changes out of your working directory, committing, and moving them back in, I'm not sure that you've got many options.

Comment: I closed my question, yet leave it here for future google searches, when someone will look for `git add --patch svn` it will come up.

Comment: In linux: `patch -p0 < file.patch `, in windows you may use Tortoise.

Comment: the `patch` command doesn't do the same this as `git add --patch`.

Comment: @Chris not the same but similar...

Comment: They're not even close. [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) applies an arbitrary patch file to an arbitrary set of files. It changes files on disk, and has nothing to do with version control. [`git add --patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) lets you interactively stage modified hunks in preparation for committing. It doesn't involve a patch file, doesn't modify the files that are being operated on, and it only makes sense in the context of Git.

Comment: @Chris for some cases it is exact the same behavior for others it is similar and for some pathological cases it is totally different, that's why it is similar. Let's agree on that.

Comment: I'm not aware of a single case where it is remotely similar. Can you give an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418277/how-to-apply-git-diff-patch-without-git-installed

Comment: That question has to do with applying a patch file created by `git diff` without having Git installed. In that case `patch` is being used as a replacement for *[`git apply`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)*, not [`git add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add). Nowhere in that question is `git add` mentioned.